# Are basically all Criminology PHD's in the UK?

Tags: phd, europe

The UK seems to have an abundance of Criminology positions. While it is attractive location from the perspective of being a familiar language and culture, the salaries are not exactly great.

Curious if there are Criminology PHD's in the Nordics, Germany, and so on.

I have done my research through various PHD searching websites, and so far it seems my assumption is correct - but also posting here to see if I am perhaps overlooking something while searching.

Comment: Is this a "Europe only" question?

Comment: Assuming this is a Europe-only, If you search in English, you will basically only get results in UK, IE and maybe Malta. For ex. PhD is not how it is called in the vast majority of European countries (Doctorat in French, Promoviert in German...)

Comment: Yes, this is a Europe only question - I should have clarified!

Comment: A bit late to the party, but be careful that you're comparing like-for-like when comparing salaries across different countries. PhDs in the UK are bursaries, not salaried positions, which means that you get the full bursary amount advertised (no taxes). In my time, French PhDs used to be salaried (so, you'd pay taxes). And in general, in a comparison of German and UK (salaried, job) positions "of the same level", the German ones will list a much higher gross salary, but after taxes and deductions which are much smaller in the UK, the UK often comes on top comparing the nett salaries. Etc...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are overlooking something. There are criminology departments in those countries and they are regularly hiring PhD students. It is not easy finding the right way to search for those positions as you often need local knowledge. The least hard way for an outsider is to find relevant departments and look if they are hiring, or if there is annual hiring cycle, or something like that.

Comment: As a criminologist in the Netherlands, look on the website AcademicTransfer for Dutch academic jobs in all disciplines including criminology.

Answer (score 2):

One issue you might be seeing is how Criminology is placed in some countries. Here in the Netherlands and, for example, in some places in Denmark and Belgium as well as South Africa etc., criminology is placed within the law school and is often part of the Criminal Law department. This is bonkers, I know, because Criminology is obviously Sociology, but it is a weird historic thing. The criminologists in those departments are every bit the sociological criminologists that one expects. In the UK, however, Criminology is more likely to be its own stand alone department or centre so a little easier to find. Beyond the countries I named, Italy and Germany are HUGE for criminology, its just they tend to do criminology in Italian and German. If you are limiting yourself to English searches, you are seeing UK search engine optimisation at work.

Comment: An idea you or anyone else looking: review the European Society of Criminology (EUROCRIM) annual conference website to see who is presenting and where they are from to get a feel for the locational spread of European criminology.  Also sign up for the criminology opportunities mailing list run out of the University of Tübingen to see European opportunities come up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing your homework well, i.e. that you are looking for the correct positions at least in french in France and in german in Germany/Austria/Switzerland, there may be a demand-offer explanation for that [(from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_prison_population):

> As of June 2023, the United Kingdom has the highest per-capita
> incarceration rate in Western Europe

;)